# Align div class to left using style in html

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, class

How do I align a div class to left, center and right using style in the html itself. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="abc" style="align: left">
code.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="float: left"`

```
<div class="abc" style="float: left;">
    code.....
</div>
```

If you are using bootstrap, you can use

```
<div class="float-left">
```

as mentioned in [bootstrap float](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning at 0px on the left:

```
<div class="abc" style="position: absolute; left: 0px;">
```

But since seems like you use bootstrap, use the class float-left.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer box model when I have another outer div:-

```
 <div class="outerdiv" style="align:left">
```

`<div class="abc">
  code.....
  </div>`
`</div>`